# Metric MAP@k for what

Tags: neural-network, metric

What is the `MAP@K` metric for?
What are you measuring? And where does it make sense to use it?

Unfortunately, I can't find much about this on the Internet. Could someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need a bit of information : where / in which article did you hear about this metric ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAP@k is normally used in recommendation systems, but also in other kinds of systems. Quoting from [here](http://sdsawtelle.github.io/blog/output/mean-average-precision-MAP-for-recommender-systems.html):

> If you have an algorithm that is returning a ranked ordering of items, each item is either hit or miss (like relevant vs. irrelevant search results) and items further down in the list are less likely to be used (like search results at the bottom of the page), then maybe MAP is the metric for you!

Some application examples are these Kaggle competitions:

- [Expedia Hotel Recommendations](https://www.kaggle.com/c/expedia-hotel-recommendations/overview/evaluation)
- [Santander Product Recommendation](https://www.kaggle.com/c/santander-product-recommendation/overview/evaluation)
- [National Data Science Challenge 2019](https://www.kaggle.com/c/ndsc-advanced/overview/evaluation)

And these are some resources with more information about it:

- [Mean Average Precision (MAP) For Recommender Systems](https://medium.com/@misty.mok/how-mean-average-precision-at-k-map-k-can-be-more-useful-than-other-evaluation-metrics-6881e0ee21a9)
- [How mean Average Precision at k (mAP@k) can be more useful than other evaluation metrics](https://medium.com/@misty.mok/how-mean-average-precision-at-k-map-k-can-be-more-useful-than-other-evaluation-metrics-6881e0ee21a9)

Answer (score 0):

MAP@k stands for Mean Average Precision at cut off k. It is a performance metrics generally used in recommender systems. You can find the details about it the link below.
http://sdsawtelle.github.io/blog/output/mean-average-precision-MAP-for-recommender-systems.html